# iPhone: Possible to dismiss keyboard with UITextField clear button?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I'm wondering if there is a way to have the UITextField clear button 'always visible'

```
textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

doesn't seem to work
.. and if it is possible to dismiss the keyboard using the button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39):

Like mentioned before it seems apple is setting the textfield focus after you clear the field.

The solution is quite simple. Just clear the field yourself, resignFirstResponder and return NO

```
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        textField.text = @"";
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: I want not to show the keyboard if user taps on clear button, but if keyboard is shown, I don't want to hide it. I just remove `[textField resignFirstResponder];` from the code above.

Answer (score 10):

In your delegate, the function

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
```

is called when the users wants to clear the textfield. If you return YES and call

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

the keyboard should go away. I don't know about the clearButtonMode, other than that you may want to set it early, preferably before adding the view to its superview.

**edit** To make sure you really resign the responder, try doing it just a little later:

```
[textField performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why the keyboard does not go away when calling textFieldShouldClear as above? It works with textFieldShouldReturn for example.

Comment: Yes, might be that after clearing, the UI forces focus to the field anyway. Try doing the resigning a little later, using the line I added to my answer.

Comment: clearing it 0.1 later wasn't helpful.  The keyboard tries to pop up then disappear, and all my other code runs for when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: @horseshoe7 I don't see why your totally unrelated issue should result in a downvote for this two year old answer.

Comment: because your solution didn't work, and your approach to solving the problem isn't very clean.  this is why the textFieldShould... delegate methods exist, so that you can say no to them and prevent something unnecessarily being executing, and as we have seen in my ACTUALLY RELATED issue, it can create undesired side effects.  (Didn't look at the date of the post and it's still relevant anyway).  Sorry.

Comment: @horseshoe7 You are not being very constructive. The OP even stated that the problem was solved. You have another problem, don't blame me for your lack of understanding your own problems and code. You state that the keyboard disappears, which sounds exactly like the intended behavior. Please just post your own question describing your own problems. Or if you must, post a better answer to this question.

Comment: it's not my intention to get in an argument over this.  But I'm sorry if you feel I'm not being constructive.  I'm trying to help the community by saying this solution is far from a silver bullet, and the more correct approach would be the one from mds (2 posts down), which IS the solution, so I don't need to post a better answer.  It's already there.  So I am being constructive and you seem to be defensive.  I don't see where I blamed you for anything.

Comment: @horseshoe7 My point is that your comments are irrelevant. 1) "clearing it 0.1 later wasn't helpful" --> this code doesn't (intend to) clear anything 0.1 later, it resigns the first responder. 2) the solution below (by mds) doesn't "dismiss the keyboard using the clear button" (as asked by the OP) Conclusion: you are talking about a different problem (possibly: "tapping the clear button when the keyboard is not visible pops up the keyboard") which can indeed be solved by adding an instance variable. But it's another problem, not the current question.

Answer (score 5):

The delay didn't work well for me. Instead I added an instance variable to the delegate:

```
BOOL cancelEdit;
```

Then in the delegate implementation:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (cancelEdit) {
        cancelEdit = NO;

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    cancelEdit = YES;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

UITextFieldDelegate textFieldShouldClear

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField] resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this odd behavior was caused by a competing gesture recognizer that resigned the first responder before the keyboard before textFieldShouldClear: was called. It seemed to be corrupting the first responder.

If you've set it up this way, ensure that cancelsTouchesInView on your gesture recognizer is set to YES. This way you shouldn't need to do anything special in the textFieldShouldClear: or textFieldShouldBeginEditing: delegate methods.